# Create a random graph based on the Degree Distribution and Clustering Coefficient Distribution

Tags: java, algorithm, graph, social-networking

I am currently working with a very large Social Network and I want to recreate this graph with a smaller dimension, using the original Degree Distribution and Clustering Coefficient Distribution.

The degree distribution is the relative frequency of vertexes in the original graph that have a certain degree.

[image]

The clustering coefficient distribution is the relative frequency for each vertex degree of two neighbours (of a vertex with that degree) to have a link between them.

[image]

Does anybody know any literature and algorithm to do this? The stuff I have found was always very theoretical..

I am trying to implement it in Java

Thanks!